# Dyadic Transpose

Tags: code-golf, array, apl

As with most APL symbols, `⍉` has different meanings when called with one argument (transpose) versus two arguments (dyadic transpose / reorder dimensions). This challenge concerns the latter, which acts similarly to `numpy.moveaxis` in Python or `permute` in MATLAB, but is more powerful.

### `order ⍉ A` when `order` has distinct entries

When all members of `order` are distinct, `order ⍉ A` is equivalent to:

- `numpy.moveaxis(A, tuple(range(len(A.shape)), order)` in Python, or
- `permute(A,order)` in MATLAB. Quoting from [documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/permute.html) of the latter:

> B = permute(A,order) rearranges the dimensions of A so that they are in the order specified by the vector order. The resulting array B has the same values as A but the order of the subscripts needed to access any particular element is rearranged as specified by order.

For example, suppose `A` is a 3D array, and let `B ← (2 0 1)⍉A`. Then B is such that `B[x0,x1,x2] = A[x2,x0,x1]` for all `x2,x0,x1`

### `order ⍉ A` when `order` has repeated entries

When `order` has repeated entries, we take a diagonal slice of the array. For example, let A be a 2x3x4 array. `B ← (0 0 1)⍉A` takes a diagonal slice along `A` to create `B` such that `B[x0,x1] = A[x0,x0,x1]`. Note that `B` is a 2x4 array: if it were 3x4, we would need to set `B[2, x1] = A[2, 2, x1]` which would be out of bounds of `A`. In general the `k`th dimension of `B` will be the minimum of all `A.shape[i]` such that `order[i] = k`.

### Example

Consider the dyadic transpose `order⍉A` where `order = [2, 1, 0]` and A is 3x4x5

```
    A =
[[[ 0  1  2  3  4]
  [ 5  6  7  8  9]
  [10 11 12 13 14]
  [15 16 17 18 19]]

 [[20 21 22 23 24]
  [25 26 27 28 29]
  [30 31 32 33 34]
  [35 36 37 38 39]]

 [[40 41 42 43 44]
  [45 46 47 48 49]
  [50 51 52 53 54]
  [55 56 57 58 59]]]
```

The result is the 5x4x3 array B =

```
[[[ 0 20 40]
  [ 5 25 45]
  [10 30 50]
  [15 35 55]]

 [[ 1 21 41]
  [ 6 26 46]
  [11 31 51]
  [16 36 56]]

 [[ 2 22 42]
  [ 7 27 47]
  [12 32 52]
  [17 37 57]]

 [[ 3 23 43]
  [ 8 28 48]
  [13 33 53]
  [18 38 58]]

 [[ 4 24 44]
  [ 9 29 49]
  [14 34 54]
  [19 39 59]]]
```

Note that when, for example, (x0, x1, x2) = (4,1,2) we have `B[x0,x1,x2] = A[x2, x1, x0] = A[2,1,4] = 49`.

If instead `order = [0, 0, 0]` and `A` as above, then we would have the output `B` be the 1-dimensional size-3 array `B = [0, 26, 52]` so that `B[1] = B[x0] = A[x0,x0,x0] = A[1,1,1] = 26`

#### Input

Here we use 0-indexing, but you may also use 1-indexing as is the APL default.

- A multidimensional or nested array `A`, of dimension *n* ≥ 1.
- A list `order` of *n* positive integers consisting of the integers {0,1,...,k} (or {1,...,k+1} for 1-index) for some *k* < *n*, in any order, possibly with repetitions.

#### Output

- A multidimensional or nested array representing the result of applying the dyadic transpose with those arguments. (The output will have dimension *k+1*.)

You may write a full program, function, etc. as allowed by the current standard on meta.

If your language has a builtin, it is encouraged to also write a solution without the builtin for the sake of an interesting answer.

#### Test cases

[Test cases on TIO](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT////1Hf1EdtE9QV1HWiDfRMYx/1LjF81LtC3THCNRgo6BgU5BgJpP1DQwJCQ9Qf9a561DZRQ8dQU8NQAUgYKYAghAdighhGCsYKJprVQHO9gv39QOYdWvGod9ej3q0aYKoTyNKsPbRC41HXoke9Wx51zHjUu/nwdH3NQytMNcBmgE1QMIUZZgyzx0jz/38A)

Reference Python implementation coming soon.

Note for reading test cases: in APL, the penultimate and ultimate axes of an array are along columns and rows in that order.

Comment: APL, 1 byte: `⍉` :P

Comment: Actually, many APL symbols just use a default second argument when called with one argument. This includes `⍉` which uses the reversed axis indices as default, so `⍉A` is the same as `(2 1 0)⍉A` if `A` is a 3-dimensional array and in general `⍉A` is `(⌽⍳≢⍴A)⍉A`.

Comment: @lirtosiast question about i/o: can a multidimensional array be represented as a pair of shape (list of dimensions) and content (all elements in lexicographical order of their indices)?

Comment: @ngn I would say no for now, but you should ask on [meta](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods) whether that format is acceptable by default.

Comment: @lirtosiast Anecdotally, Dyalog APL internally stores arrays as `[number-of-dimensions,first-dimension-length,second-dimension-length,…,last-dimension-length,first-element,second-element,…,last-element]`.

Answer (score 4):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 34 [bytes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9429/43319)<sup>[SBCS](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS)</sup>

This is [my colleague](http://www.dyalog.com/meet-team-dyalog.htm#Roger)'s code (slightly modified from [Roger Hui](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roger_Hui): [*A History of APL in 50 Functions*](http://www.jsoftware.com/papers/50/), [chapter 30](http://www.jsoftware.com/papers/50/50_30.htm)), posted with explicit permission.

Anonymous tacit infix lambda (can be used as drop-in for `⍉`).

```apl
{⍵[(⊂⊂⍺)⌷¨,¨⍳⍺[⍋⍺]{⌊/⍵}⌸(⍴⍵)[⍋⍺]]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##vVHBSsNAEL33K@a2CURrEuM9lIoVbCRJUQk5BKReigrtRUIuCkVjtuhB7Fk8BC8eVJQe45/Mj8S3kXyBILvMvNmdefsem5xP1o4vksnZSV2nLD8ijfNLteVK5@KzKo2qZPmGMmJ5ixSnXORddGZcfGks3wH19i7O6jHP71guePEw8Di/ql63eH6PKvB7iOHOIOgkp1M0CRJGtLHuxCyfTZalcA/7AQ5d33ePkL1RuD8KBcsXEGiGqWsmIVik1m@loAIW2bSpp@DfDbyh4lOiV1CmNelGacyqEt6elOLrJSx9P3b1qnS0hqNhIKcls9t3LL0zm87@U@34L1rBCa02WZgULg0poAPqkw@BIXJAIRH1yAVCJQxBsIWh7b2wKvEtBLP1Dw)

`{`…`}` dfn; `⍺` is left argument (axes), `⍵` is right argument (array)
E.g. `[2,2,1]` and `[[[1,2],[3,4]]]`

`⍵[`…`]` index the array with:

`(⍴⍵)[`…`]` the shape (lengths of axes) of the array, indexed by:
  `[1,2,2]`

`⍋⍺` the grading vector (the indices that would sort them) of the axes
   `[3,1,2]`
  `[2,1,2]`

`⍺[⍋⍺]{`…`}⌸` use the sorted axes as keys to group that, and for each group:
  `[1,2,2]` → `{"1":[2],"2":[1,2]}`

`{⌊/⍵}` find the lowest axis length
   `{"1":2,"2":1}` → `[2,1]`

`⍳` generate the indices in a Cartesian system of those dimensions
  `[[[1,1]],[[2,1]]]`

`,¨` ensure that the indices of each coordinate is a vector (would be scalar if `⍵` is a vector)
  `[[[1,1]],[[2,1]]]`

`(`…`)⌷¨` index into each of those with the following:

`⊂⊂⍺` the axes (doubly enclosed; once for `⌷` to select those cells along the first and only axis, and once for `¨` to pair up each vector on the right with the entire set of axes on the left)
   `2 1 2`
  `[[[1,1,1]],[[1,2,1]]]`
 `[[1],[3]]`